# Is there a way to prevent a user from updating an iCal outside of an app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, icalendar

I am writing an app that uses iCal sync'd from iCloud.  I want the users to be able to update the app's iCal ONLY from the app, because I have to format the data entered, and need to validate it's correct.  The app's iCal resides on an iPad; as long as the other users also have the iPad app, they can update the app's iCal, but not from outside the app.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just as an idea: You could jailbreak the devices and hide iCal on them. But I don't know if this is an option.

Comment: no, it's not an option... lmao

Comment: This is a bad idea -- in your app, you need to deal with the fact that users can use iCal outside your app.

Comment: You just could check all new events since your app was last opened and verify they are correct. If it's not the case, show them to the user to modify these items.

Comment: rdelmar: they CAN use iCal outside the app, their OWN iCal, not the apps iCal...

Comment: So, @spokane-dude you need to be more clear. Your app has it's own "calendar" feature, so by referring to it as "iCal" is probably misleading to those trying to help you.

Comment: WrightsCS:  I edited the original question... is it still not clear?  And I was under the impression that iCal was for iOS and Calendar was for Os X.  Not true?

Comment: This is terrible. Never do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done. The user is king of his content. What if they don't like your app and delete it? Now they might have a few items stuck in iCal ? Now what?

The only kind of workaround I would suggest here is creating your own calendar app, and the only way your items "exit" your app is by sharing it with iCal. That way iCal only has a view of what your app is doing.

But if you really want to own the items in your app (edit, delete, add items), you'll have to create your own cal app that does not share items elsewhere.

Comment: Agreed. Also @spokane-dude, what are you using the built in calendar API for? It sounds a little bit like you're using it for the fact that it does syncing for you, not because it integrates with the user's calendars. If that's the case, you should create your own calendar data model and store the objects in core data and then sync to iCloud manually. If you really want users to be able to see the events, you'll need your own server and sync with that and then ask the user to subscribe to a read-only ical feed.